# When I added default in foreign-key, "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet." occurred

Tags: django, django-models, wagtail

I am developing Django&Wagtail blog app.

Unfortunatly, `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.` is occurred.

If there is no default, the app works properly. However, if I added default, it does not work...

I researched some article but they could not help me.

```
class hoge(models.Model):
    """
    ...
    """

    page = models.ForeignKey(
        "blog.BlogIndexPage", on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        verbose_name=_("blog"),
        default=BlogIndexPage.objects.latest("id"), # add here
    )
```

Environment:

```
Mac(Mojave 10.14.6)
Virtualenv
python 3.7
Django 2.2.4
wagtail 2.6.1
```

Error:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do queries like that inside field definitions, because they are executed at import time when other models are not initialized yet.

You should remove that default; you can set the default page in the form that creates the page object, or the view.

Answer (score 0):

From Django documentation [Field.default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#default):

> The **default** value for the field. This can be a value or a callable object. If callable it will be called every time a new object is created.

So simply change it to a callable object like this:

```
def get_hoge_page_default():
    return BlogIndexPage.objects.earliest('id', '-id')

class Hoge(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(
        "blog.BlogIndexPage", on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        verbose_name=_("blog"),
        default=get_hoge_page_default(),
    )
```

**WARNING**: This approach can cause you Race Condition - imagine that you are in Django admin panel trying to create new `Hoge` object. On the form, you will see the latest `BlogIndexPage` available when the server was generating HTML for you.  If one person creates new `BlogIndexPage` between server sends the form to you and your `submit` action, the value in `Hoge.page` will not be latest!

I would like to show you a better approach:

```
def get_hoge_page_default():
    return BlogIndexPage.objects.earliest('id', '-id')


class Hoge(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(
        "blog.BlogIndexPage", on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_("blog"),
        null=True,
    )

    def clean(self):
        if self.id is None and self.page is None:
            self.page = get_hoge_page_default()
```

Reference: [Model.clean](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) and [ModelForm validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform)